# asp.net core npgsql connections

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, npgsql

I was wondering if anyone was able to get the npgsql patch working for .net core as explained on this page http://fxjr.blogspot.com/2013/06/performance-improvements-when-creating.html . For me when I create Npgsql connections it takes about 1012ms or alittle over 1 second for 10,000 connections which could be an issues when your having a lot of traffic. The patch shown on that link has it working so that 10,000 connections are open within 35ms average. This is the code that I used inside my .net core application.

```
   var conn = "server=127.0.0.1;userid=postgres;database=modelcars;";

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(conn);

            }

            sw.Stop();
```

I did the same test with Sqlconnections and it did 10,000 connections in 39ms .

Comment: That patch is ancient and definitely won't apply against modern versions of Npgsql... What version are you trying to use which does 1012ms for 10000 connnections?

Comment: I am using version 3.13 of NPGSQL and for .Net Core RC2

Answer (score 0):

Yes patch must've been applied, I just ran the test using .Net Core 1.1.0 and NPGSQL 3.19 on my Mac and got the response of

1st run: **34ms**

2nd run: **4ms**

3rd run: **4ms**

I am using Postgres 9.6 and this is my code

```
 public string Test()
        {
            var connectionString = "Database_Config";
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            for(int i=0; i<10000;i++) {
    var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
            }




 sw.Stop();

 var time_takes = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            return "hello";
}
```